# Cannot connect to my linux server MySQL DB

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

My MySQL connect code below is 'Catching' this error: "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."

My DB is on my linux website and I have remote access enabled using % so anyone can access the DB.

My code is .NET C# and I have a winform.

```
        string server = "http://www.mywebite.net";
        string database = "mywebsite_app";
        string uid = "admin";
        string password = "Password";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
        database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
        MySqlConnection dbConn;
        try
        {
            dbConn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            dbConn.Open();
            if (dbConn.State.ToString() != "Open")
            {
                this.Text = "could not open database connection";
            }
            else
            {
                this.Text = "database connection opened";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)  // catch on general exceptions, not specific
        {
            this.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

Thanks for any help...

Comment: The database is on a windows machine so windows has to allow remote access to the PC.  So in windows user accounts you have to create a group that allows remote access.  I would start by getting a remote terminal session working.

Comment: describe the location and particulars of the server running mysql

Comment: Check firewall issues : exceptions must be set for MySQL port.

Comment: The DB is not on a windows machine, its on a Linux server. The server is a shared hosting site, hosted by hostgator...the MySQL database and user was created in cPanel and MyPHPAdmin. I will check my firewall port.

Comment: i used to use hostgator quite a bit, but it certainly was thru PHP that connected localhost or what not, see [this](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/how-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database). I don't remember an exposed public facing mysql server with them in the baby, hatchling world they set up. This is a good [Doc](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/how-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database-remotely) too. In fact, start there.

Comment: Their cPanel allows remote ip addresses to allow remote access to the DB and they support wild cards...so I used % to allow anyone or any app to connect if they know the user and pw...

Comment: I created an outbound rule on my win7 machine to open up port 3306 but as I think about it, I believe this feature is to really allow someone IN via port 3306 into my win7 machine to access the DB but my DB isn't on my PC, its on my Linux website...

Comment: Your windows client 3306 is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

If you mysql database is on remote hosting, then you usually out of luck try to connect to that database remotely.
The hosting provider usually blocked remote mysql access.

Try using ssh-tunneling. 
download putty 
     http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/

open the command line, and execute putty from the installation directory

```
putty username@remote_mysqlhost -L 3306:localhost:3306
```

or you could use the gui, fill the address with your mysql remote, but dont open connection yet.

go to ssh tunnel, add new forwarded port 3306, and the destination as localhost:3306.

as of why the destination is localhost, it is because the destination is what the ssh session see. because you already connected to your remote server in your ssh session, thus, the mysql host is local.

this could also be a set up for dmz. 
you can create a dmz gateway using putty to tunnel trough any computer within the dmz network. but the computer behind the gateway, wont publicly expose to the internet.

dont forget to klik the add button to make sure the configuration is added to tunnel list.

open the connection and use your password (ssh user and password, usually the same as webhosting control panel user and password

Now, instead connecting to your remote mysql, you can connect to mysql trough localhost. it would be tunneled by putty to your remote mysql.

try to connect using mysql administration tool first. to test wheter or not the connection is success.

the way ssh tunnel work is almost the same as vpn, from user view. 
but without the hassle of setting up vpn server on remote host.

Comment: Thanks, really, for that info Henry but this is a win32 app that going to be distributed as share ware and my clients are not going to go thru all of that to get a connection. I was hoping I could get the connection transparently to anyone using the app. As I said, I have added '%' to my hostgator site to allow remote access into the DB from the outside.

Comment: Hhmmm. In that case ,  you could try the web service approach. That way it would also overcome security issue. It is always a bad idea exposing mysql publicly. Ssh tunneling could also be embedded in win32 application. Navicat and winscp are 
good examples of embedding ssh tunnel into win32 apps.